# Get specific Generic for an item in a Record

Tags: typescript

I have a record that is like so:

```js
// custom interfaces for each key
interface Alert { 
   name: string;
};
interface Notice { 
   code: number;
};

// allowed keys
type ApiKey = 'alert' | 'notice';

// config type
type ApiConfig<T> = { endpoint: string; myType: T };

// define a map under specified keys (in my code each is defined via a function, but still a const)
const ApiMap = {
   alert: { endpoint: '/alerts',  } as ApiConfig<Alert>,
   notice: { endpoint: '/notices',  } as ApiConfig<Notice>
};

// given key returns config type (with generic)
export type ApiConfigForKey<A extends ApiKey> = typeof ApiMap[A];

// returns the typed config for the key (with generic)
export const getConfig = <E extends ApiKey>(apiKey: E ): ApiConfigForKey<E> => ApiMap[apiKey];

const alertApi = getConfig('alert'); // is the correct type and has the generic.
const noticeApi = getConfig('notice'); // is the correct type and has the generic.
```

I want to now access the generic defined for each record item. For example,

```js
// T should be the generic of the specified config selected by apiKey.
const set = <E extends ApiKey>( apiKey: E, body: T ) => {}; 

set('alert', { name: 'My name' } ); // works as it's type `Alert'
set('notice', { code: 500 } ); // works as it's type `Notice'

set('alert', { code: 500 } ); // errors because body is not `Notice`
set('notice', { name: 'My name' } ); // errors because body is not `Alert`
```

Any help with getting / using the Generic for the selected record item would be appreciated.

There may be errors in above code as I made a simplified version of what I'm doing.

Comment: If it's simplified but has errors or does not properly represent the issue, then it's not really a [mre] and might not be as helpful as it could be;  Right now the biggest issue is: `ApiConfig<T>` does not depend on `T`, and writing "`we use T later`" doesn't help the compiler.  Could you [edit] to make it actually depend on `T` to [avoid a large stumbling block](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--)?  Also, could you remove the annotation on `ApiMap`? It obliterates information you apparently care about.

Comment: updated with the suggested fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body should be `ApiConfigForKey<E>['myType']` since that's the property that holds the body:

```
const set = <E extends ApiKey>(
  apiKey: E,
  body: ApiConfigForKey<E>['myType'],
) => {};
```

Testing:

```
set('alert', { name: 'My name' }); // works
set('notice', { code: 500 }); // works

set('alert', { code: 500 }); // error
set('notice', { name: 'My name' }); // error
```